# How to composite in a background picture?

Tags: compositing-nodes

This is a diagram:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RcAW.png]

Look at the background carefully...

This background was made in compositing: http://www.filedropper.com/xtruder22

However, I wanted to know whether I could put a better background gradient from a .jpg or .png file? e.g.: http://www.shoutot.com/stockimage/black-gradient-background.jpg http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/042/c/3/gradient_toshiba_background_by_daproba-d5uo24e.png

Many thanks

Comment: I'll have a look at the answers tomorrow.

Comment: Also you don't have to use an image to get a nice gradient, you can use a gradient texture or colour ramp in blender to generate nice gradients, either as a material on a plane as part of the render or as another render layer or scene to composite into the final.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with the mix node.

Use the *Input* > *Image* node to load in the background image, then use the *Mix* node with alpha to put it behind.

Node setup:
[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't do gandalf3's method. So I chose yours.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is an *Alpha over* node:

[image]

1. Add an *Image* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Input > Image*) and open your background image:

   [image]
2. To crop or scale your background image to fit your render, add a *Scale* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Distort > Scale*).
   Set the *Coordinate Space* to *Render Size*, and set the scale type. If your background image is larger than the render, you probably want to crop it. (select *Crop*) However, if it is smaller and you want to scale it up, select *Fit*:

   [image]
3. Connect the nodes as shown above.

Comment: Wondering what version of Blender you're using. Our version 2.69 does not have so many menu items as in your snapshots!

Comment: I couldn't do your method. Thanks a lot anyway, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Developer I'm using 2.69 too.. Are your sure you were using composite nodes?

Comment: Well, not. Now we can find them :) Thanks. [Compositing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes).

Comment: @gandalf3 You used Alpha over node when CharlesL used Mix. Which is better? Thanks

Comment: @TimTimmy, I'm not really sure that one is better than the other. However, the mix node allows you to mix it different ways, and I think the alphaover node gives you more control over premultiply.

Comment: @TimTimmy For just a simple operation like the one above, both will give an identical result.