# Cannot find Background Images feature in Blender 2.8

Tags: experimental-features

Cannot find Background Images feature to add in a photo in Blender 2.8

Where is it?

Comment: Blender 2.8 is not ready for production or end user testing yet

Comment: It is back actually in the camera section.

Answer (score 79):

Background images are gone in Blender 2.8+, at least in the [traditional pre-2.7# sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPFKa.png).
The old system was aging and prone to failure as described in the [Proposal: Replace background images with Image Empties in 2.8x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj3er.png), and it has been retired due to inherent limitations.

Information was stored as User Interface data, as such if you opened a file without the [*Load UI* option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9g1x.png) checked they would appear to be missing, when in fact they simply weren't loaded.

Saving the file would then silently erase them, without warning or explicit user intervention leading to permanent data loss.

They were also hard to manipulate and had duplicate functionality, having thus been replaced by more modern and robust solutions.

## Alternatives

1. Either use them as *Empties* like you could before, if you are using them as reference images to model over. This allows for greater control of size, position and display options.
2. Use them in the newly added *Camera Background* feature, if your goal is aligning a camera to an existing photo or matching perspectives, for later compositing a 3D scene over existing footage.
3. Import them as planes using the *Import Images as Planes* addon like
   in previous versions

## Workflow

You can now add most background images in Blender from a dedicated entry in the *3D View > Add > Image* menu.

[image]

Three options are available if you manually activate the *Import Images as Planes* addon from *Edit > User Preferences > Add-ons > Import Images as Planes*). [Background and Reference Images are basically different presets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135141/what-is-the-difference-between-reference-and-background-image-in-2-8) for the same underlying tool.

1. Reference - Act as regular objects, visible from both sides, non renderable

[image]

2. Background - Can be set to display always in front or background, non renderable

[image]

3. Image Plane - Actual renderable mesh with geometry and a material

You can control visibility settings from the *Properties Window*, like making it visible only for orthographic views, display always in front, adjust transparency and control backface culling for empty based solutions.

You can also use them from the new *Camera Background* feature, available in the *Properties Window > Object Data > Background Images* for any currently selected Camera object.

[image]

If you require a background image (other than an *Image as Plane*) to be visible in your render, either set it up a [world shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/how-do-you-use-an-image-as-the-world-background/8929#8929), use a [Spherical HDR as an environment map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81007/how-can-i-render-an-object-with-an-hdr-background/81011#81011), [images as planes](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images) for actual geometry, or [render with a transparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent/1307#1307) and overlay the result over your image through post processing using either the [Blender Compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-to-composite-in-a-background-picture) or any external image editor.

Answer (score 24):

Now Blender uses Empties to Add Images as Backgrounds

Go to the Orthographic View in which you want to add the background image(Top,Front, Side etc)

In the Object mode you can go <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and Select `Image`

[image: Adding Images as background[1]]

Now select `Background` and it will open the file browser so you can chose your Background Image from Files.

Now switch to the next orthographic view (i.e.: Front, Back, Right, etc) and repeat the process and this time select Image which is appropriate for for selected view.

These Background Images are only view-able in Orthographic Mode and could be scaled, moved and rotated according to your taste.

**The section below has been merged from the @l0lock comment:**

And don't forget to uncheck "display perspective":

[image]

Comment: don't forget to uncheck "display perspective": https://i.imgur.com/SeiXC9w.png

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> go down to *Image*.

You can also do it on the camera by selecting it and adding a background image, or adding image as plane (must turn it on first) or add node with image.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to any orthographic view then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Image* and add a *Background* (not *Reference*) image to your viewport, that image sticks to that ortho view only, just like the old system.

You can make a collection to store all of them.
Also remember that it is the *Background* not the *Reference* one you are looking for.