# Add planes as a reference

Tags: modeling

What I want to do is for the flight sim world (XP11 now).
One of the helpful things with max was the ability to use planes to put a plan on in order to get correct shapes etc for a model. Essentially there would be 3 views, top, side and front.

I'm trying to build a poly aircraft hanger on which photo textures can be baked.

Comment: Hello and welcome, please use a descriptive title, also avoid any extraneous text that is not essential to answer your question

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135141/what-is-the-difference-between-reference-and-background-image-in-2-8