# Add background image from script for different views

Tags: modeling, scripting, 3d-view

How can I add `background images` for different views (`Top`, `Front`, `Back`...) from a script/addon in `Blender 2.8`?

The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.load_background_image) does not specify a lot:

> `bpy.ops.object.load_background_image(filepath="", filter_image=True, filter_folder=True, view_align=True)` Add a reference image into the background behind objects.

When I call the operator, the image is placed on the origin, normal to `Z`, and **as a `reference image` not a `background image`** ([see distinction here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135141/what-is-the-difference-between-reference-and-background-image-in-2-8)).

How can I position the added images in place?

---

Also, kind of related, what `filter_image` and `filter_folder` do?

*Thank you.*

Comment: Consider using `bpy.ops.object.load_background_image(...)`  The filters are to show only image file formats and folders in the filebrowser.

Comment: I'm sorry I copy-pasted the wrong method, I meant ``load_background_image`` which loads the image as a reference, which I think makes not much sense... Fixed the question.