# what is the name of the blender feature in which a 2d artwork/image is used as a guide to create a 3D model of the artwork

Tags: modeling

I have been watching some blender tutorial videos, in which it is like a 2D art is traced in other to build the 3D model of it. like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAO4C_8y0w8&t=1301s. What is this feature called in blender ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8/

Answer (score 0):

Background Image. Hit the plus sign to the left of the outline panel, and it's located about 3/4ths of the way down the panel.

Answer (score 0):

It's called background image. In Blender 2.8 it is much better and easy to use ,
You can find it at:
Shift+ A  > Image > **Background**