# I set an background image but i can't actually see it all

Tags: interface, image

[image: On the right there is the background image i set]

I'm new in blender.
I want to know if anyone has the same problem and can tell me how to fix it, if it's possible.
(I'm using fedora as OS)

Comment: I think that my question is quite different because I actually already seen those answers and try them but the result is the same: I can set a background image but I can't see it at all (I see only a part of the image)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: I will try to find out what information is best to add. It will take a while. I'm a little disappointed that the question was marked as a dublicate but I hope that in the end everything will be resolved and will be useful to someone. It is not my intention to create inconvenience. (and sorry if I use the comment like a chat. If it's not reccomended I will stop)

Comment: Please edit and help is understand how to help you. Don't worry about marking as duplicate. Edit the question and it can be re-opened

Answer (score 0):

In 2.79 [background images](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/editors/3dview/properties/background_images.html) have settings in the Properties shelf on the right of the 3d viewport. There is *Opacity* slider which by default is set to 0,5 (50%). Set it to higher value if you want the image to become less transparent.

[image]

See more about how to setup background images while in 2.79 [How do I set a background image while I am editing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing)

Note that [in 2.8 background images are used in another way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the problem. I still see only a part of the image

Comment: @MihailBobeica that's exactly that information you should include into your question; as you can see we couldn't guess what was wrong with the image on your screenshot. Additionally mention how you create that image; which settings for background image were used; which version of Blender (official or test builds) etc. Your question was marked as duplicate because it *looked like* duplicate given the information provided

Answer (score 0):

## Background images will only be displayed in:

1. Camera Prespective view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. Any of the **preset** Orthographic views:

   Front/Back (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)

   Right /Left (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)

   Top/Bottom (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>)

To toggle between Prespective and orthogonal view use <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but I did some research before asking the question so I had already found this answer. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Maybe I should add more information but I don't know exactly what kind of information to give.