# How to set backround image in Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, objects, compositing-nodes, image

[image: My current nodes]I am trying to set a background image in Blender 2.8 Beta.

The image is what I have right now for nodes. I set it to world node and it has a background when I render it but it is all mixed up.Do you know what I am doing wrong? (I am a beginner with Blender).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8/

Comment: You mentioned a background image, but you just posted a node setup for a material. Something doesn't add up

Comment: I thought the problem with the background image not working was something wrong with my nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Texture Coordinate node and connect it to your Image Texture node, otherwise blender won't be able to map the texture properly. You can then move, rotate and scale the texture using a Mapping node.

For comparison, without Texture Coordinate node:

[image]

And with:

[image]

EDIT: After seeing your screenshot, I see the issue: you are editing a MATERIAL node, when you should be editing the WORLD node. Simply select "World" from the dropdown list on the upper left corner:

[image]

Comment: Hey so I added in the Texture coordinate and I tried rendering again but there was no background image.