# My background reference image isn't showing within blender?

Tags: modeling, image, sculpting

Good evening everyone. I'm a person new to blender, and I was watching a few tutorials that would take me through the process of creating/rendering a creature design in 3d, and from what was shown, I would need to have a side profile sketch of the design to import into blender as a background reference. I've attempted to open the image a couple of the different ways, through accessing the backgroung images tab as was shown inthe tutorial, and by simply dragging and dropping the image into the program. I've also tried changing the format of the file between .jpg and .png, to little avail. Is there someone who could help me through this issue? I'll link the image in question below.[image: Dummount creature]

Comment: Are you in perspective mode? Because you can see bg image only in ortographic mode. [Num5]

Comment: Alright, I gave it a shot. I am able to see the picture now yes, but I am unable of moving it around to readjust it to my liking, which was shown to be possible in tutorials I have watched

Comment: Also whenever i try to move around the screen when I have a 3d object within the file, the picture disappears and fails to properly return, making me have to delete and reinput the file again

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8/110533#110533

Answer (score 1):

Select the image and look at the object data. You can see there are two checkboxes: Display Ortho and Display Persp. You can also set the transparency etc.

Also look in the scene collection and make sure the disable selection is not turned off (the white arrow). If you cant see this then click on the filter icon in the header.

[image: look at the object data]

[image: Make sure the white arrow is not deselected]