# Apply displacement to a video?

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, add-on

Has anyone come across a method to apply displacement to videos? When I import the video it comes in as an empty and doesn't provide me with the option to use any modifiers. I would like to apply displacement that changes as the video progresses. If anyone can point me to some resources, it would be greatly appreciated!

Niko

Comment: Import videos as an [image as plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8/110533#110533)

Answer (score 6):

In your preferences, make sure you enabled the "Import images as planes" add-on

[image]

Go to Add (or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ) > Image > Images as Planes

Then choose your video.

Add your modifiers :

[image]

Set some keyframes and play.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gorgious! Just a follow up question... Do I set the keyframes as the displacement texture?

Comment: What I did but didn't show is that I added an empty, set it as the texture coordinate in the displacement modifier, and simply keyframed the empty at 0,0,0 at frame 0 and then something like 0,0,20 at frame 100. If it isn't clear enough I'll update the answer

Answer (score 2):

Subdivide the plane and you will be able to apply the modifiers.