# Cannot find Background Images feature in Blender 2.8 - follow up

Tags: 3d-view, interface, add-on, image, transparency

I'm new to this forum, don't have "reputation" pints to answer, that's why I'm doubling this post:
[Cannot find Background Images feature in Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8/110533)

So, it's possible to import images and give them options similar to old background images, transparency, scale, dimension, foreground/background overlay... that's nice.
However, how can we limit the visibility to specific views, like before.
I want 6 vies to be assigned to Top, Bottom, Left, Right, Front and Back views.
Can anyone explain how to do it simple way like it was in 2.79?

Best,
Hazooka.

Comment: One more thing. It's crucial to lock the images only to orthographic views. They should not be visible in an isometric or perspective views. Just like it was before.

Answer (score 1):

The options are still there.

1. Navigate to *Top/Front view* + add the image and check *✓ Only Axis Aligned*
2. To limit visibility to orthographic view > uncheck *✓ Perspective*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tip.
However there is another thing that needs sorting out.
After we set up the images we end up with the rectangles constantly visible in the isometric/perspective view.
Can we hide the wireframe on those rectangles and leave only the contents/drawing visible in the orthogonal views? Hide the edges perhaps? Make just the image visible and the mesh invisible?

Best,
Hazooka.