# How to set a constantly visible background in Blender editor?

Tags: modeling, image

I'd like to set some background in the editor (while editing objects). But not putting it on a plane, instead make it like environment, like in a game engine.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8/

Answer (score 1):

Add a hdri to the World's background (as Environment Image) and enable it in the Viewport Shading.

[image]