# Blender 3.6 import image as plane >> restrict view of plane to a viewport?

Tags: image

Trying to restrict image plane to render from specific viewports: top in top view, front in front view, etc using Blender 3.6.  How do I do this?  Apparently in earlier versions of blender, one would:

In the 'Object Properties' tab, you can restrict the visibility of the image planes to specific viewports.
For example, if you only want the top image visible from the top view, you can click on the 'Restriction Toggles' icon (a monitor-like icon) and enable/disable the visibility for different viewports (Top, Front, Side, etc.).

I see nothing similar in v3.6 with the plane selected, or the object or the image.

Unable to use image plane as tag, which is unfortunate.

Thx

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110533/19307

Comment: As far as I know, you can't restrict image as plane to an specific view because is basically a 3D plane with an image. You probably looking for background image, but you can't render that. Add menu> image > background image

Comment: Thanks.  Apparently I am an idiot, as I cannot find 'Properties' in 3.6.  And it sounds like from the link that the import must be configured a bit differently, and cannot limit image as planes like you can references.  Appreciate the tip.

Comment: Emir you beat me to it.  Thanks much.