How is tutorial image displayed as background in the viewport?
How is this background image displayed in the viewport? I cannot see it in the outliner.
Here Ian is UV unwrapping/texturing or whatever its called. But he appears to have the image in the viewport the entire time.
I cannot see a reference image or anything else in the outliner.
I know its a bit of a drab question but I'm curious to know how he's doing this?


Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8/

This is quite possibly what's going on here yes.

Stupid question: do you only have this one screenshot? This looks like a still from a video, is Ian not explaining in the video what he is doing?

Yes there are other screenshots. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whPWKecazgM but you've already answered it as you're a legend thank you!!

Hi not sure why the title had the word tutorial added to it.
How is this image displayed as background in the viewport? I cannot see it in the outliner
How is this tutorial image displayed as background in the viewport? I cannot see it in the outliner

The image is set as background image in the camera properties:

You can determine this by the following hints:

He is in camera view, the camera symbol in the 3D Viewport is filled with white and not only the outline (and also the rectangular frame with the dashed outline shows that).

If there was a plane or something with the reference image parented to the cube, there would be another orange symbol after the green one in the outliner.



This is what it looked like if there was something parented to the cube:


Thanks a lot Gordon

You are right. Didn't know that you could see the parenting in the outliner - learnt something new again ;)

@Chris That's one of the things I always look for when people are kind enough to post screenshots including the outliner, but maybe not explain what else they have done to an object... because there you can usually see if objects have modifiers, animation keyframes, vertex groups etc. and also if they are parent of something (I only wish sometimes there would be more informations down the hierarchy of a child object, too, but I guess this would lead to endless rows of symbols in the outliner :D
