# Background Options?

Tags: image

Rookie here.
I have a little bit of experience with Google Sketchup and 3d printing and I have used adobe photoshop quite a lot.  Totally new to blender though.
I am wanting to do a project where I have a character doing some basic movements.  I have figured out how to import character with rigging and movements.
I am just wondering about the background (setting?).  Is there anywhere that I can access a bank of background choices?  Like a stadium, or stage or living room, workout room etc....
I'm actually having a difficult time even posting this question since I don't know how to properly tag it.  I am likely referring to the background incorrectly.
Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps [HDRI](https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/) is the term you're looking for :). They're not shipped with Blender, but are [very easy to add](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81007/).

Comment: Hi there - another possible approach is to render your image with a transparent background (Render Properties->Film->Transparent) and then in the compositor you can mix in any image as the background. Many example on this e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-to-composite-in-a-background-picture

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to both of you for your kind responses.
I have learned quite a bit over the past few weeks.  What I was looking to do was simply create a floor and a wall where I could have a character doing stationary movements.  The easiest thing to do was two planes and add textrues.
For fun I purchased my son minecraft for windows and he made me a floor and wall and we were able to export and then import into blender.  Very cool!
Thank you again for the tips.  I will use the HDRI in future for more complex projects and the background images are also a great suggestion.